# How to dynamically set the width of main content based on weather side nav is opened or closed in material Angular

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I am new to angular and material framework. I am trying to create a page which has below structure[image]

The button on right side of Admin portal works perfectly fine and it hides and shows the side menu.
Most of the code is default code generated by angular.

In order to shift the left menu below top navbar i used [fixedTopGap]="64" on mat-sidenav.
To expand the top menu to take full width i used class main top bar in below line:-

```
<mat-sidenav-content class="mainTopBar">
```

Css for main topBar:-

```
.mainTopBar
{
margin-left:0px !important;
}
```

Doing so gave me full top menu, but now the problem is whatever content i am trying to place using ng content gets stuck to the very left. 
How can i provide margin to ng content based on if left menu is opened or not.

Here is my html code :-

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container">
  <mat-sidenav #drawer class="sidenav" fixedInViewport="true"
      [attr.role]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'dialog' : 'navigation'"
      [mode]="(isHandset$ | async) ? 'over' : 'side'"
      [opened]="!(isHandset$ | async)" [fixedTopGap]="64">
    <mat-toolbar class="Namebar">Menu</mat-toolbar>
    <mat-nav-list >
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 1</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 2</a>
      <a mat-list-item href="#">Link 3</a>
    </mat-nav-list>
  </mat-sidenav>
  <mat-sidenav-content class="mainTopBar">
      <mat-toolbar color="primary">

        <button
          type="button"
          aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
          mat-icon-button
          (click)="drawer.toggle()"
          *ngIf="isHandset$ | async">
          <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
        <span>Admin Portal</span>
        <button
          type="button"

          style="position:absolute;margin-left:200px;"
          aria-label="Toggle sidenav"
          mat-icon-button
          *ngIf="!(isHandset$ | async)"
          (click)="drawer.toggle()"
         >
          <mat-icon aria-label="Side nav toggle icon">menu</mat-icon>
        </button>
      </mat-toolbar>
     <ng-content style="margin-left: 200px !important; "></ng-content>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
</mat-sidenav-container>
```

I tried using margin-left:200px but that even that didn't work. 
On Side bar open it shoul look like:-
[image]

Based on Yin answer, the screen which i am getting is :-
[image]

Comment: ng-content is not a html tag. What if you wrap the ng-content tag in a div, and give that div a margin-left of 200

Comment: but that will then always have margin-left as 200. if the side nav is closed it should be 0 px;

Comment: I highly recommend you to use flex boxes. It will give you automatic adjustment without needing to calculate margins.

Comment: @NikhilSrivastava you can switch a class depending on if it's open

Comment: @RomanMahotskyi Can you let me know how can i use it here, i am new to UI and i am not much aware about flex boxes, a sample code would help a lot.

Comment: @PierreDuc Let me try

Comment: @NikhilSrivastava What exactly you are looking for? Sidebar menu on open should overlap the content or It should move content to the right?

Comment: @RomanMahotskyi it should move content to right, when its closed the content should take full screen. I have added a new image to show the same

Comment: @NikhilSrivastava take a look at this example - https://material.angular.io/components/sidenav/examples (The 'Autosize sidenav' section)

Comment: @RomanMahotskyiThe example show every thing i already have. It does not contain a top nav bar which is fixed to 100%.

Answer (score 2):

Finally i found the issue. 
I made top nav bar(mat-toolbar) as fixed and width to 100vw.
Added autosize here `<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container" autosize >`

And it started working as expected

Answer (score 0):

Don't use margin-left, just add autosize on the mat-sidenav-container :

```
<mat-sidenav-container class="sidenav-container" autosize >...
```

Comment: Hi Yin, With this approach if i remove margin left from .mainTopBar
{
margin-left:0px !important;
}
in that case the top blue bar remain 200 px away from my left end of screen/. If left menu is closed only then it takes full width of screen. What i want is that blue navbar should always be 100% of screen size and left menu showuld open and closed below that based on clicks, and according ng content should behave